# Using Applicative instance of composed functors

Tags: haskell, applicative

I have two functions of the form

```hs
foo :: Int -> IO String

bar :: Int -> IO Integer
```

which basically live in the functor given by the composition of `(->) Int` and `IO`.
Now, having a function of type

```hs
baz :: String -> Integer -> Float
```

I would like to lift it to the `Int -> IO _` context using applicative syntax like

```hs
foobarbaz :: Int -> IO Float
foobarbaz = baz <$> foo <*> bar
```

If I do this the compiler yells at me with

```
Couldn't match type `IO String' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: Int -> String
        Actual type: Int -> IO String
```

as if it was trying to use the applicative instance only for `(->) Int`.

I thought applicative functors composed, so that I could use the applicative instance for the composed functor. Am I wrong? Or should I just provide more information to the compiler?

I tried also to enable `TypeApplications` to specify explicitly the functor I want to use, but I realized that I can't write `(->) Int (IO _)`. Is there actually a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought applicative functors composed, so that I could use the applicative instance for the composed functor.

That is correct, but imagine that we take `f ~ (->) Int`, then the types are `(<$>) :: (a -> b) -> (Int -> a) -> (Int -> b)`, and `(<*>) :: (Int -> (a -> b)) -> (Int -> a) -> (Int -> b)`, but this does not match with the types since, `baz` requires a `String` and an `Integer`, whereas `foo` returns an `IO String` and `bar` an `IO Integer`.

You can make use of [**`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2) to lift the `baz` function to use the result of `IO` actions:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

foobarbaz :: Int -> IO Float
foobarbaz = liftA2 baz <$> foo <*> bar
```

`liftA2` will here thus convert a `baz :: String -> Integer -> Float`, into a `liftA2 baz :: IO String -> IO Integer -> IO Float`. This is thus a function that then matches with the output types of `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, basically I need to lift one functor at the time. I could also do `(liftA2 (liftA2 baz)) foo bar`. Is there any specific reason why the compiler is not able to do it with just one lift?

Comment: @marcosh: there is one lift to lift over `(-> Int)`, but another to lift over `IO`. But you are right that you can use `liftA2 (liftA2 baz) foo bar`. Lifting always lifts over "one" applicative level (and due to the type system, that is always the outermost). It thus does not "recurse" to more levels, since that could result in ambiguity.

Comment: @marcosh To do it in a single lift, you can explicitly compose the functors with `Data.Functor.Compose`, at the cost of some newtype wrapping/ unwrapping. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose